# Zeppelin - How to directly display a pie-chart after creating it through REST API?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a requirement where I want to create a pie chart or another chart through the Zeppelin Notebook REST API, and then open up that notebook with directly displaying that pie-chart without any user interaction.

I can create the notebook with the desired visualizations, but when the notebook is opened, it always displays data in table mode, and user has to click on pie-chart button or the bar-chart button to see the visualization. How can I bypass this click, and open the notebook directly with the pie-chart visualization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be available in version 0.8.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ZEPPELIN/versions/12339144